# Share single instance of class between activities in android app?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I am creating an Android application in Android Studio, I am coding in Java.

My app will have a class that handles a connection to a SQLite database, it will also have classes abstracting access to the database, i.e. a list of friends and lists of messages sent and received that are sorted by friend.

I currently have three activities, the main activity, one for a list of all friends and one to show a specific chat conversation.

My question is what is the best practice to share an instance of a class, i.e. database class, and other classes (say friend manager) between my activites. I would prefer not to copy these classes for each activity but rather keep a single instance for the lifetime of my app.

One example would be the "FriendManager" class, it has interfaces that supplies a list of friends, removes and adds new friends etc. I want to use it both when creating the list of all friends, but also to use it when showing a conversation as it will hold references to the "MessageManager" class that takes care of loading messages from the database (and remote locations).

Comment: Your manager classes seem to fit what Google's architecture pattern calls "repositories". The typical solution for setting those up is to use a dependency inversion framework. For Java, the default dependency inversion choice tends to be Dagger 2, though this comes with a significant learning curve.

Comment: I would just toss them into a `Service`, then bind to the `Service` in each `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a Singleton Pattern as shown as Pattern 1 in https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

While Google's best practice is not to use SQLite Directly but via Database Rooms
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

In that they still say

> If your app runs in a single process, you should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object. Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process.

And then implement it in their examples in the same way as the Singleton Pattern
As seen in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#6

Comment: Thank you! For me the Singleton Pattern seems the most appealing. Could I implement something similar for my other classes that are not directly dealing with the database?

Comment: I've not tried it, but I believe it is a generic pattern and should work on other classes (It does seem to be a generic Java Pattern https://codesjava.com/java-singleton-design-pattern )

Comment: I will mark this as answered, but would love to hear if anyone has another opinion. Especially about the singleton pattern, as this is something that I have heard about but never applied myself.